# Retrieving DOI for a combination of author, title and date/year

Tags: doi

I want to retrieve the DOI for a combination of a title, the first author, and the year. I wanted to use the query method, but there is no date or year filed in it. It also does not allow me to use a title. Here is the example article I want to get its DOI:
title: "The generic name Mediocris (Cetacea: Delphinoidea: Kentriodontidae),
belongs to a foraminiferan"
author : Mark D Uhen
Year: 2006

I tried this but it failed (although I could not find any filed name for the year):

```
last_name='Uhen'
title = 'The generic nameMediocris (Cetacea: Delphinoidea: Kentriodontidae), belongs to a foraminiferan'

q = works.query(author=last_name, title = title)
```

Here is the error I got:
UrlSyntaxError: Field query title specified but there is no such field query for this route. Valid field queries for this route are: affiliation, author, bibliographic, chair, container_title, contributor, editor, event_acronym, event_location, event_name, event_sponsor, event_theme, funder_name, publisher_location, publisher_name, translator

I appreciate any help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, the link would be:

https://api.crossref.org/works?query.author=Uhen&query.bibliographic=The%20generic%20name&filter=from-pub-date:2006-01-01,until-pub-date:2006-12-31

(I don't know what software you are using, but it might be one step towards a solution to change the field name `title` to `bibliographic`)